# Loop in database using perl

Tags: mysql, perl, loops

I need to extract each character from the input (input are numbers) and check it against my database, if the number is present the corresponding rows will be printed. But in my code the loop doesn't work and only the first character is printed.

```
use dbi;
my $seq=<stdin>;
my $r=my$seq;
my $db="hnf1a";
my $user="root";
my $password="";
my $host="localhost";
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=$db:$host",$user,$password);
my @w= split(//, $r);
print @w;
foreach my $b(@w)
{
my $sth=$dbh -> prepare("select an,ano from mody having ano = '$b' ");
my $rv=$sth->execute();
while (my @row =$sth->fetchrow_array())
{
print @row; 
}
}
my $rc=my $sth->finish;
}
print "database closed";`
```

Comment: What is this you posted? It's full of nonsense. `use dbi;`??? `my $r=my$seq;`??? `stdin`??? `my $sth->finish;`??? 2 `{` but 3 `}`???

Comment: @ikegami Alright. Why don't you tell me what's wrong in that?

Comment: The code you've shown us would not run at all. Please include the actual code you are using. (Minus any usernames and passwords, of course, but with _no other changes_.)

Comment: @duskwuff The Code Does Work. But it's only reading the first charachter. It does not read the remaining characters I put. I think I'm stuck here. Could you tell me If there are any other codes I can put?

Comment: no, there is an extra `}` that will prevent the code from even compiling. (Though on case-sensitive filesystems, `use dbi;` will fail even before that.)   Please edit the question and copy and paste your exact code, indented 4 spaces (you can select the text after pasting and press the {} button in the editor to do this) so it is formatted as a code block.

Comment: @ysth this is my actual code

Comment: Then you should start by asking help fixing the compile errors and warnings you're getting  ...after trying to fix them yourself. There's no point in helping you with the problem you asked about until you get the basics right first.

Comment: And if that's your actual code, then `use strict; use warnings qw( all );` is missing. Always always use that.

Comment: @ikegami . Alright mate help me fixing the compile errors. My basics are totally fine.

Comment: If the code doesn't compile, one could argue that the basics are probably not "totally fine".

Comment: you may think it is your actual code, but in fact it is not (if it is even printing the first character).  *copy and paste* your actual code

Comment: or, let's make it easy.  copy and paste just the part through the `print @w` and we can help you get at least that part working (it won't with the code as is)

Comment: `$ perl garbage.pl` Unmatched right curly bracket at garbage.pl line 25, at end of line / syntax error at garbage.pl line 25, near "}" / Execution of garbage.pl aborted due to compilation errors. (And that's not even running in strict mode!)

Answer (score 4):

Database:

```
mysql> select * from mody;
+----+---------+------+
| id | an      | ano  |
+----+---------+------+
|  1 | 123     | 456  |
|  2 | abc     | 567  |
|  3 | hello   | 5    |
|  4 | world   | 5    |
|  5 | goodbye | 6    |
+----+---------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
use 5.020;
use autodie;
use Data::Dumper;
use DBI;

my $dsn = 'dbi:MariaDB:database=my_db;host=localhost';
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, 'root', '');
my $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT an,ano FROM mody where ano = ?');

my $input = "56";
my @numbers = split //, $input;

for my $number(@numbers) {
    say "rows matching input <$number>:";

    $sth->execute($number);

    while(my @data = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
        say "\t@data";
    }
};
```

Output:

```
rows matching input <5>:
    hello 5
    world 5
rows matching input <6>:
    goodbye 6
```